# Stripe webhook: can get event ID but not type

Tags: php, json, stripe-payments

In my webhook when I put `$event_id = $event_json->id;` I get the event id (example: id:evt_1EJ1NdIcP22cq9aQWsTXf8DY).

However, when I put `$event_type = $event_json->type;` I am expecting to get 
`charge.succeeded` or `charge.failed`, instead I am getting `customer.source.created`.

I've searched the internet up and down, can't find the answer. What should I use to get what type of charge it was (`charge.succeeded` or `charge.failed`). Maybe this great community can help me solve this one.

Comment: Use var_dump($event_json) - you can see a content of webhook and find field with data you needed

Comment: I get all of them. When I run `var_dump($event_json);
http_response_code(200);` all the contents are there, somehow I can't get the ones that I need, such as "status", "paid", "type" via `$event_json->data->object->`. Not sure what to think of it.

Comment: Could be that your webhook callback is filtering out the ones you are looking for?